# SQL query for messages vote

Tags: php, mysql

I need to list messages of best votes for one user (user ID: 100).

I'm trying the following query but there is a problem .

```
SELECT t.topics, m.msg_id, SUM(v.vote) AS totalvote 
FROM topics t, messages m, users u, votes v 
WHERE t.topic_id=m.topic_id 
and m.user_id=u.user_id 
and u.user_id='100' 
and v.user_id=u.user_id 
and v.user_id=m.user_id 
GROUP BY v.msg_id 
ORDER BY totalvote DESC 
LIMIT 0,10;
```

How can I do this?

My database structure (simplified) :

```
-------------------------
DB users 
-------------------------
user_id (int) primary

-------------------------
DB topics 
-------------------------
topic_id (int) primary
topic (varchar)

-------------------------
DB messages
-------------------------
msg_id (int) primary
topics_id (int) index
user_id (int) index

-------------------------
DB votes
-------------------------
vote_id (int) primary
msg_id (int) index
user_id (int) index
vote (int)
```

NOTE: My English is not good and I am sorry for mistakes.

Comment: Since you have `m.user_id = u.user_id AND v.user_id = u.user_id`, you're only counting votes that someone made on their own messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to join with the `users` table, since you're not using anything from that table. The join with `votes` should be on `msg_id`, not on `user_id`; you want votes from everyone, not just votes from the author of the message.

```
SELECT t.topic, m.msg_id, SUM(v.vote) AS totalvote 
FROM topics AS t
JOIN messages AS m ON t.topics_id = m.topics_id
JOIN votes AS v ON v.msg_id = m.msg_id
WHERE m.user_id = 100
GROUP BY m.msg_id
ORDER BY totalvote DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```